# Retrieving Sql FileStream files

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, filestream

We have over 200gb of data in sql filestream db. So, can someone suggest me what is the best & fastest way to extract the filestream files?

I am planning to use C# app to extract the files (by looping thru one by one). Is there any other method available or do you guys know how to extract the files quickly using C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Extract them once to put them somewhere else? Or does your program really need to repeatedly extract all of the files over and over again, one by one?

Comment: Yes, We need to extract the files one by one from the DB and store them in a folder. (Actually we need to move all the extracted files to amazon S3.)

Comment: How much faster you need code to be compared to slow solution you already have? (I assume you planning to show sample code with measured timings so people can suggest improvements)

Comment: Right now I have the normal c# code to get the file from the filestream. (which is the general code everyone is using).

Answer (score 2):

If you are extracting a large number of files - which it sounds like you are in this case - and you have access to the SQL server machine you can just copy all the files from the folder on disk.

This is version dependent but you may find them here for SQL Server 2008:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
```

This will contain all the files named with the GUID which you could potentially rename to something more readable by looking at your database tables in your C# application.

If you don't have access to the SQL server machine then reading them off remotely and saving each file is probably the way to go. Just make sure you have sufficient bandwidth and check to see if running the queries in parallel results in a speed improvement.

See this link for more information:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128657/How-Do-I-Use-SQL-File-Stream

Comment: I couldn't understand what do you mean by copy all the files from the folder on disk. In my understanding the sql filestream files are encrypted and stored in the sql server (Correct me if I am wrong), we need to use some program/API to retrieve the files(in my case c#).

Comment: I do not believe they are encrypted on the local disk. You should be able to just open them like a normal file on the SQL server machine assuming you have some information about the file type.

Comment: +1 It is possibble if you use FileStream to save file in database. Database actually did nothing but create a dictionary to maintain those files, certainly maintain them in transaction. However, if you stop SQL Server service, you can just manipulate files like regualr files.

Comment: @ljh: Ok. But how we know which file belongs to what? I mean the files in the filestream folder seems to be different and without any extension like .pdf, .xls & etc.. How to identify the same?

Comment: I got this from microsoft site "Individual files stored in a FILESTREAM column cannot be opened directly from the NTFS file system. Streaming FILESTREAM data works only in the context of a SQL Server transaction." See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream.aspx

Comment: @user972255: Take a look at the codeproject article I linked above under "Where are the Files Actually Stored" you can see that the files can be opened directly from the filesystem. You can look at your tables in the database to match up the filestream GUID with the file name and extension. It doesn't necessarily look like this is recommended by Microsoft but it does seem possible. If you're not happy going this way then just grab each file individually using SQL but you were originally after the fastest method.